# Извлечь регулярным выражением все файлы png находящиеся в кавычках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Выражение "#'([^']+)'#" извлекает все строки находящиеся в одинарных кавычках (использую на php через preg_match_all). Мне же нужно выражение, которое извлекает не только в одинарных, но и двойных кавычках и только строки в которых есть расширение .png

Для примера, выражение извлекающее все строки внутри одинарных кавычек:

```
preg_match_all("#'([^']+)'#" , $txt , $m));
var_dump($m[1]);
```

Во входной переменной **$txt** может быть совершенно разный код - js,php,xml,html. Поэтому не важно что снаружи кавычек, важно определить, что внутри кавычек имя png файла.

Comment: Не плохо было бы в вопросе пару строк для примера написать.

Answer (score 1):

Это сработало:

```
"#(\"|')([^\(\"|')]+\.png)(\"|')#"
```

Также есть хороший вариант, на котором пока остановился(php):

```
preg_match_all("#[\"']([^\"']+\.png)[\"']#" , $txt , $m);
```

Comment: `["'](\w+\.png)["']` а если вот так? А зачем у вас в середине `[^\(\"|')]`?

Comment: `w` не захватывает все строки, в которых есть тире(-). А без этой части `[^\(\"|')]` выражение жадничает и в некоторых случаях перехватывает лишку от других кавычек.
Вот так у меня тоже хорошо работает: `preg_match_all("#([^\"']+\.png)[\"']#" , $txt , $m)`

Comment: Если что, то то выражение в ответе не сопоставит строки со скобками и вертикальной чертой (что вероятно, ошибка)... А также строки с внутренними кавычками другого типа и, напротив, сопоставит строки с разными кавычками, что скорее условность.

Comment: Спасибо! Подумаю, пока-что остановиться на этом:
`preg_match_all("#[\"']([^\"']+\.png)[\"']#" , $txt , $m);`